# Galaxy localhost reference data uploading

Tags: bioinformatics, galaxy

anyone knows how to upload reference files to a Galaxy localhost? I've tried using FTP like FileZilla which couldn't connect to the localhost, I've tried data manager provided by galaxy which resulted in errors(Fatal error: Exit code 127 (Error); Fatal error: Exit code 126 (Error)). Anyone can help???

This galaxy has nothing to do with Samsung Galaxy by the way.

Comment: BTW, if you know any helping references or forums to learn about the galaxy, pls leave a comment, thanks~

Comment: you should ask https://biostar.usegalaxy.org/